# self = this but cannot access self.function within a callback

Tags: typescript, this

I have the following block of code to store the correct reference to `this`. 
I am using Mongoose for `Models.Image`.

```
class some {
    public one() {
        var self = this;
        this.another(); //edited: this.another() is not a function
        Models.Image.findById(id).then(function(data) {
            self.another(); //self.another is not a function
            ....
        });
    }
    public another() {
        ....
    }
}
```

The linter is showing `self` to be `this` but when I execute it, gives me error. What is happening here? How to solve it?

The class is a route handler bound to express routes.

I would like to add more. Calling `this.another()` within the `one()` (not callback) is still giving me `is not a function` error. Somehow, `this` is not referencing the class.
What may be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem is with the limited code you included. It looks like it should be ok, but since there's a problem it will be best if you included more of your code. On a side note, you don't even need this `self = this` as you can just use an arrow function.

Comment: How are you calling `one()`?

Comment: I have updated the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using an arrow function `() => {}` instead? This way there is no need for the assignedment of `this` to `self`.

Comment: It's highly likely that you are specifying `some.one` as some kind of callback, which is missing context information, as suggested to by @JohnnyHK's comment. You would need to change that to `() => some.one()` or `some.one.bind(some)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Edited: The class is a route handler bound to express routes.

Probably the problem is here.

Because of how the method `one` is called, `this` is not bound to an instance of the class `some`. The issue is not about the callback. At the first line of `one`, `this` already has a wrong value:

```
var self = this; // self has a wrong value because this has a wrong value
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem was with the way route handler was bound. I had used `some.one.bind(some.one)`. I replaced it to be `some.one.bind(some)`. Thank you.  After I knew where the problem was, the solution was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604848/express-js-this-undefined-after-routing-with-app-get

Comment: Here ist some MDN docu of bind, including a great example: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score -3):

another() is expected to be within public one() :

```
class some {
    public one() {
        var self = this;
        Models.Image.findById(id).then(function(data) {
            self.another(); //self.another is not a function

            ....
        });
    }
    public another() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Maybe better like this:

```
class some {
    public one() {
        var self = this;
        Models.Image.findById(id).then(function(data) {
            self.another(); //self.another is not a function
            ....
        });
        another() {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What are you saying was the problem, and how did you fix it?

Comment: It is the way you call self.another. another() needs to be in public one().