# route class not able to access local function #typescript #express

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

In the code below I get 'undefined' error for 'loglogMePleasePlease' function.

Could someone please help me out with this.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'logMePleasePlease' of undefined

*I am at flabbergasted, this kinda error makes me question **everything** I have coded so far.*

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { db } from '../db/lowDb'

export class employeeRoute {
    router: Router
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        this.router.get('/', this.default);
        this.logMePleasePlease('SFDSFSDF');/*This call works fine!*/
    }
    public logMePleasePlease(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    public default(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        /*****Error when execution gets to follwing line:
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'logMePleasePlease' of undefined
        ******/
        this.logMePleasePlease('asdad');
        res.send({
            status:'ok',
            message:'employee api home'
        });
    }
}
const employee = new employeeRoute();
export default employee.router;
```

Comment: I am just staring in abyss and wondering where I went wrong :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the way JavaScript binds `this` when calling a function.

Let's take a couple of examples and show what I mean as well as how to go about fixing it.

```
class BindingTest {
  func() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

const test = BindingTest()
const testFunc = test.func
```

Now, as you can see in this example, we have the `test` object which presents the `func` method, as well as the `testFunc` variable which holds a reference to that method.

It is important to keep in mind the way that JavaScript moves values around (and adds functions to classes), specifically that everything is a value. In this case, when we assign `const testFunc = test.func`, what we're doing is taking the `BindingTest.prototype.func` value (the function we defined on the class) and referencing it directly.

As a consequence, when we run the following:

```
testFunc()
```

We will see that it prints out `undefined` rather than the `BindingTest` context...

That's rather odd, because when we run the following:

```
test.func()
```

We get the context printed!

So as I alluded to, this is the result of calling the function via the object's prototype invocation strategy (in which case `this` is bound to `test`) and calling the function as an isolated value (in which case `this` is `undefined`).

The fix is actually very simple, JavaScript provides the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method which allows you to associate a `this` context with a function value.

```
const boundTestFunc = test.func.bind(test)
```

Now, if we go and call `boundTestFunc`, we'll get our `BindingTest` context printed out as we would expect.

I hope this clarifies the "why" behind what you're seeing. In your case: the fix will be to simply use the following code in your constructor.

```
this.router.get('/', this.default.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Helped mightily :)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your router messes up the context of the function 'default', that's why this equals undefined.

You can try binding the func to the right context in the constructor:

`this.default.bind(this)`

But this is messy. Are you sure it's a good idea to have a separate router for every route? I would create the one and only router and provide it to every route class in constructor..

I'm using to following pattern in creating routes taken from one of the popular tutorials, which is a bit arguable because of extensive use of static methods, but works nicely for me:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from 'express'


export class IndexRoute {


    static CREATE(router: Router) {
        console.log('[IndexRoute::create] Creating route /');

        router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
            new IndexRoute().index(req, res, next)
        })
    }


    index(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        console.log('[IndexRoute::index]');
        const data = { status: 'ok' };
        res.status(200).json(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604848/express-js-this-undefined-after-routing-with-app-get

Comment: Good suggestion Daniel, I will update constructor to take in router.
(And thanks for quick answer, I was about to grab jumbo pack of 'Lays chips' to binge on)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, here is sample code using classes and the `use` method on a `Router` (see example at bottom of documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)).

**server.ts**

```
import { Test } from './test';
import express from "express";
import compression from "compression";

export class Server {
    private app: express.Application;
    private port: number = 3000;
    private test: Test;

    constructor() {
        // setup server
        this.app = express();
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));   // needed for POST requests
        this.app.use(express.json());   // needed for POST requests
        this.app.use(compression());

        // create classes
        this.test = new Test();

        // tell app to use routes
        this.app.use("/test", this.test.router);

        // start listening
        this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log("Node Express server listening on port " + this.port);
        });
    }

}
```

**test.ts**

```
import express, { Router, Request, Response } from "express";

export class Test {
    public router: Router = express.Router();
    private testVar: string = "Hello World";

    constructor() {
        this.router.get('/', [this.get.bind(this)]);
    }

    private async get(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
            // return
            res.status(200).send(this.testVar);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    }

}
```