# Context Binding in Express.js Controllers Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oop

I am working on an Express.js project with a UserController class, with methods like getAllUsers and findUserById. To use these methods in my User router, I find myself binding each method upon creating an instance of UserController to ensure the correct "this" context ([refer to this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604848/express-js-this-undefined-after-routing-with-app-get)).

```js
// UserRouter.js

const express = require('express');
const userController = require('./UserController');

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.get('/users', userController.getAllUsers.bind(userController));
userRouter.get('/users/:id', userController.findUserById.bind(userController));

module.exports = userRouter;
```

**Is there a more efficient and maintainable way to handle the context binding issue in Express.js UserController?**

An alternative solution is to bind all methods in the UserController constructor. However, this approach doesn't feel clean as it necessitates modifying the constructor every time I add a new method.

```js
// UserController.js

class UserController {
  constructor() {
    this.getAllUsers = this.getAllUsers.bind(this);
    this.findUserById = this.findUserById.bind(this);
    // more method bindings as needed
  }

  // Methods implementation
}

module.exports = UserController;
```

Comment: Don't make your controller a `class` in the first place? Do you instantiate it multiple times? Do you call any of the methods from multiple places (or from other methods)?

Comment: @Bergi I employ classes for dependency injection purposes, as explained on this Reddit comment https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/gs6t55/comment/fs3oxpn/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions instead of methods:

```
export default class UserController {
  constructor(dependencies) {
    this.dependencies = dependencies;
    this.getAllUsers = (req, res) => {
      // implementation
    };
    this.findUserById = (req, res) => {
      // implementation
    };
  }
}
```

You can also declare them as class fields:

```
export default class UserController {
  constructor(dependencies) {
    this.dependencies = dependencies;
  }
  getAllUsers = (req, res) => {
    // implementation
  };
  findUserById = (req, res) => {
    // implementation
  };
}
```

This is has [some problems](https://www.charpeni.com/blog/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think), but they're mostly related to inheritance and I doubt you want to subclass your controllers (use composition instead).

Alternatively, use a `function` instead of a `class`:

```
export default function UserController(dependencies) {
  return {
    getAllUsers(req, res) {
      // implementation
    },
    findUserById(req, res) {
      // implementation
    },
  };
}
```

where you can refer to the `dependencies` by closure, not as a property of `this` (which again is not bound).

Answer (score -1):

```js
// UserController.js
class UserController {
  //inject services here if needed and you can access them through "this" inside methods implementations
  constructor() {}

  getAllUsers() {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        // "this" here refers to the UserController class
        return res.status(200).json({});
      } catch (error) {
        next(error);
      }
    };
  }
}

module.exports = UserController;
```

as for the router handler it would like this

```js
// UserRouter.js
userRouter.get('/users', userController.getAllUsers());
```

If you are using typescript you should type it as such

```js
interface IConfigController {
  get: () => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response | undefined>;
}
```

so it is basically a function that accepts whatever needed and returns a handler that returns a promise

the promise returned should return whatever your function returns so in case of my example i am returning the response or undefined in case of an error that is why it is typed `Promise<Response | undefined>`

Comment: this effectively works! However, before closing the question, with these solutions, how can we type the IUserController interface? Assuming the interface was: 

interface IUserController {
    getAllUsers(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>;
}

Comment: So given that you are gonna use trycatch block like i did
you would type it to something like that
interface IConfigController {
  getAllUsers: () => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response | undefined>;
}
Keep in mind in the return Promise i have Response | undefined because i usually return res.status(CODE).json(PAYLOAD)
but given that you don't follow this practice of returning the response you should type it as any or void

Comment: i edited the answer with the interface as well so it is more readable. i hope it helps